# Vertices disappear after doing a "disolve edges"

Tags: modeling

[image]

I often end up with that problem. I must do something wrong, or I misunderstood the concept.
I don't understand why my vertex doesn't stay in place when I do a Disolve Edges in that configuration. Can anyone explain?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way *Dissolve Edges* works by default, it also dissolve the vertices, but you can deactivate the *Dissolve Vertices* option in the *Operator* panel, I agree that it should be the default setting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! (late comment, though I had already answered)